# A name that describes this type of turn-based battle system

Tags: terminology

I am thinking of a turn-based battle system that follows this workflow:

```
While True
  Get next character
  Determine character's action
  Execute action
  Check Battle Status
end
```

This is a straightforward battle system: there's a queue of battle characters, and on each iteration, it grabs the character at the front of the queue and has it perform an action. Once the action is performed, it gets pushed to the back of the queue.

Everyone gets an equal opportunity to perform an action and it simply rotates through all the participants.

When the loop breaks, end-battle processing occurs (eg: victory, defeat, escape, etc)

Is there a name for this particular type of turn-based battle system?

Comment: Can you be more precise in what your mean by a "character"? Is that player characters? Non-player characters? Both? If this is only player avatars, I'd say this is some kind of hot seat mode.

Comment: All combatants participating in the battle.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turns,_rounds_and_time-keeping_systems_in_games#Turn-based) for more info, but it seems this type of system falls under a player-alternated, ranked, turn-based system. (AKA "I-GO-YOU-GO")

*Ranked* meaning the first player is first every round. This assumes your loop always executes the same; meaning when a player has performed, they go to the end of the queue. Furthermore, there is no additional system to manipulate a players order in the queue, which might be based on player stats or other outside factors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps looking for the "Conditional Turn-Based Battle" as coined by Final Fantasy X? In this type of battle system, a sequence is determined based on character statistics and is stored. For example, a starting battle sequence could look like this:

- Ally 1
- Ally 2
- Enemy 1
- Ally 3
- Enemy 2
- Enemy 2
- Ally 1

When the battle begins, Ally 1 would use an action. If the action that Ally 1 affected the outcome of the "action list", then it would be adjusted accordingly. Then, the next unit in line would get to act. Assuming nothing else was affected, this would be Ally 2 who would be followed up with an action from Enemy 1.

[You can read more about it here.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_System#Conditional_Turn-Based_Battle)

Comment: "Conditional" sounds like a good way to describe it, since who the "next character" is may depend on a number of various factors (whether they can move, how fast they can recover from previous action, etc).